# Issue with Bourbon / Neat Grid - grids dont align correctly

Tags: css, sass, bourbon, neat

I am new to Bourbon / Neat framework, and the past 2 days i've been setting my environment up, but i am having issues configuring the Grid.

The issue is that no matter how much i try, there are some spacing issue when it comes to the grid, there is a small space in between columns in the grid, which is giving me a headache, and i have no idea what is causing it.

[image]

As you can see from the image, the right column, is slightly on the left, is this a common occurrence in neat?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: would you mind sharing a codepen for the above? Haven't had issues with grid alignment with Neat so far... might be something else.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you should use the `@omega` mixin. From the [documentation](http://thoughtbot.github.io/neat-docs/latest/#omega) : Removes the element's gutter margin, regardless of its position in the grid hierarchy or display property.

Comment: It was the visual grid, it was offset by some pixels due to chrome calculations. Thank you all for the replies :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the visual grid, this can be off by a few pixels. Please see the documentation here:

http://thoughtbot.github.io/neat-docs/latest/#visual-grid

> The overlaid grid may be few pixels off depending on the browser's
>   rendering engine and pixel rounding algorithm.

Hope this helps